# JPQL Not working but SQL is

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpql, entitymanager

I'm working with EntityManager + Hibernate and I'm having a problem!

The code I use:

```
 public Integer getNumServicosEmAtraso() {
     try {
         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -2);

         String jpql = "select count(s) from Servico s where (s.indtemlaudo = false or s.indtemlaudo IS NULL) AND s.dtentrega <= :date AND s.dtEntradaRecoleta IS NOT NULL ";
         Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql);
         query.setParameter("date", calendar.getTime());
         return ((Long)this.getDao().getSingleResult(query)).intValue();
    } catch (Exception e) {
         log.error("Erro no getNumServicosEmAtraso", e);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This code trace the following log:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(servico0_.CODSERVICO) as col_0_0_ 
    from
        servico servico0_ 
    where
        (
            servico0_.indtemlaudo=0 
            or servico0_.indtemlaudo is null
        ) 
        and servico0_.dtentrega<=? 
        and (
            servico0_.dtEntradaRecoleta is not null
        )
353374 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [DATE] - [Wed Jan 03 00:00:00 BRST 2018]
353395 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor - extracted value ([col_0_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [0]
```

As you can see, the result is 0.

If I run the same query direct on my MySQL database, I got a different result:

**Query:**

```
select
    count(servico0_.CODSERVICO) as col_0_0_ 
from
    servico servico0_ 
where
    (
        servico0_.indtemlaudo=0 
        or servico0_.indtemlaudo is null
    ) 
    and servico0_.dtentrega<='Wed Jan 03 22:15:57 BRST 2018'
    and (
        servico0_.dtEntradaRecoleta is not null
    )
```

**Result:**

```
col_0_0_: 2
```

Any tips about what could be?

(There's no erros/exception. Just the hibernate trace log)

Thank you!

[UPDATE]

I realized now that this WHERE is not working:

```
and servico0_.dtentrega<='Wed Jan 03 22:15:57 BRST 2018'
```

Probably it's just the .toString() and this isn't the real value.

using this o got the same result:

```
and servico0_.dtentrega<='2018-01-03'
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** As you are using `java.util.Date` here, make sure you annotate that field accordingly in you entity:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
java.util.Date dtentrega;
```

**2)** Set parameter using an overloaded `TemporalType` version:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql);
query.setParameter("date", calendar.getTime(), TemporalType.DATE);
```

Comment: Yes. I'm using @Temporal annotation.

Even adding TemporalType.DATE in setParameter didn't change the result.

I updated my question, I figure out something